# How do I get Expand-Archive working on Windows 2008R2 using PowerShell 3.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, unzip, powershell-3.0, compression

I am in the process of investigating upgrading our PowerShell framework to version 3.0; we currently have many scripts written for 2.0 on Windows 2008R2 servers.  I am finding some issues that I can get around easily but I have discovered a bit of fun with the Expand-Archive cmdlet running under PowerShell 3.0 and dotnet 4.0 framework.

Looking here on [CodePlex](http://pscx.codeplex.com/workitem/30302) I see the following comment

> Upon further investigation the Expand-Archive command is not compatible with 
>       dotnetframework 4.0 when running in 64 bit powershell session.  to run this 
>       command in dotnet framework 4.0 ensure that you import the module to:
>
> ```
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Pscx 
>
> Then the 32 bit powershell.exe can be invoked and the Expand-Archive command 
> will run properly. This fix applies to windows 2008 R2 64 bit
> ```

I have been able to get the Expand Archive to work locally on a Zip file but when remoting from another PowerShell 3.0 environment I get the following error:

> Expand-IHIArchive : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException:
>   Expand-IHIArchive:: error occurred in Expand-Archive with parameters:
>   FlattenPaths = False ; LiteralPath =
>   \Deploys\Packages\POWERSHELL3\CodeReleasePackage.zip ; OutputPath
>   =\Deploys\Packages\POWERSHELL3 ; PassThru = True ::

Is there a way to get this to work?  Or at least figure out from the remote what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by adding the Modules to my environment when they load by putting all the PSCX directory locally to my own copy of PowerShell, basically I load up what PSCX modules I need depending on the PowerShell version.  This allows me to control the right version, and make sure the modules are loading properly without worrying about centrally installed modules and this way I can set up my environments easier by having everything packaged up in a structure I like.

This got me past the Expand-Archive issue.